# Is there a way to isolate SVG styles?

Tags: css, svg, scope, styles

```html
<svg>
    <defs>
        <style>
             .test {
                 fill: red;
             }
        </style>
    </defs>
    <circle class="test"></circle>
</svg>
<div class="test">test</div>
```

How to make works class `.test` only for **SVG** element.
Is there a way to isolate **SVG** classes/styles?

Comment: In this case since you are using fill it works only with svg elements. Also you can use a selector  only for svg elements: `svg .test{...}`

Comment: Anyway, since it is an inline-style, it will never be applied to the div

Comment: @vals That's incorrect. CSS rulesets defined within inline SVGs will apply to any elements within the whole DOM they match. If you added a `border` property declaration to the `.test` ruleset in the example above, it would absolutely apply to the `<div>`.

Comment: @Sean You are right! I had always thought that it would be "inside" the svg. You can always learn something new !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, by putting the SVG in the **shadowDOM** of a W3C standard Web Component

- https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/shadowdom

supported in all modern Browsers.

Answer (score 4):

The `shadowDOM` approach broke styles within the SVG for me. So here's an alternative:

```js
let svgs = document.getElementsByTagName("svg");
for (let i = 0; i < svgs.length; i++) {
  let svg = svgs[i];
  let img = document.createElement("IMG");
  img.src = `data:image/svg+xml,${encodeURIComponent(new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svg))}`;
  svg.parentNode.replaceChild(img, svg);
}
```

It converts `svg`s to `img`s with data URLs. Simple!

Answer (score 0):

You could also just do:

```
<svg class="MY-SVG-CLASS" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 303.182 218.285">
<defs><style>svg.MY-SVG-CLASS .cls-1{ …
```

Add a class to the svg and add the class to the inline style of the svg itself.