# How to scope the css properties of <style> tag within a svg?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, svg

I have a `<style>` tag inside a svg image with `background-color` property set to white. And I am dynamically adding this svg to the HTML. As the background-color is set to white, all other svgs on the webpage are inheriting this property which is unwanted. It seems the properties are applied globally, but I want to scope the property to this single `svg` or this single `div`

Earlier there was `scope` attribute for `<style>` which is now removed. How can I achieve this, specially in `angular`. Angular `view encapsulation` is not working in this case.

```
<div class="svg-image">
    <svg>
        <style>
        svg {
            background-color: white;
        }
        </style>
        <g>
        .
        .
        </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Edit:
[A similar question is answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61794966/18875617)

Comment: Give the svg an id and target that

Answer (score 0):

apply custom class to your svg as folows,

**app.component.html**

```
<div class="svg-image">
    <svg class="svg-background-white">
        <g>
        .
        .
        </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

**app.component.css**

```
.svg-background-white {
  background-color: white;
}
```